# I have a problem in groupby 2 column , I got an error

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, average, valueerror

```
df['USDT_volume'].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='60min', key=df['Datetime'])).mean().dropna()
```

my error: `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: Please, provide a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

the `key` parameter of [`pandas.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) should be a **string**, not a Series:

```
pd.Grouper(freq='60min', key='Datetime')
```

full command:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='60min', key='Datetime'))['USDT_volume'].mean().dropna()
```

Comment: but I got this: 'The grouper name Datetime is not found'

Comment: I want to calculate mean of df ['USDT_volume'] for an each hour in df['Datetime'], help me please

Comment: There was another error in your command, you should slice after grouping (otherwise the grouping column is not available)

Comment: error: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Comment: Please provide a fully reproducible example.

Comment: I use this : df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='60min', key='Datetime'))['USDT_volume'].mean().dropna()

Comment: I meant a (**minimal**!) reproducible example of the DataFrame